# cannot access iis 7 / vista remotely

Tags: iis-7, windows-vista, remote

I have build a web site and deployed it on my iis 7 / vista.
I can access the site from localhost but not from the network.
computers on the network have "ping" working to my machine and I have turned off my firewall.

Is there any tweak in iis 7 to allow remote calls? Any other way to check this?

Comment: What ip address is the web site bound to?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the website in IIS and click on **Site Bindings**.
2. Click on the host in the list and click **Edit**.
3. Make sure that the **Port** is set to **80** and that **IP Address** is set to **All Unassigned**.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a DNS issue. When I access the site from IP it works. Strange though how in my previous xp/iis6 machine it worked out of the box and now there is this DNS issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't already done this, turn on both network discovery and file and printer sharing.

Comment: -1. Network Discovery and File & Printer sharing have no bearing on a web site running in IIS.